# TableView row action image

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

In a tableview I want to put images in the row action using this

```
let action = UIContextualAction()
action.image = "image.png"
```

When I first placed an image which was 512 x 512 pixels it didn't fit in the cell.

So I shirked the image to be just the size I want it to be which was 35 x 35 pixels, it became blurry and it looks bad when you look closely at it.

Are there any ways to shrink an image with a png format and also keep the resolution?

Comment: The best way is using SVG(PDF) image instead of png, otherwise you need to scale the image by code

Comment: how do you use a PDF?

Comment: you should export the image from adobe illustrator or sketch as PDF, then adding it to assets file then change "scales" property from inspector to "Single Scale"

Comment: Sorry, I've never used assets before so can you tell me [ the change "scales" property from inspector to "Single Scale" ] part more specifically?